# jQuery Datepicker for Start Date and Number of Days

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to create a form that uses Jquery Datepicker to choose the Start Date and then a select field that allows number of days. 
Then the form needs to have hidden fields for ...

CheckInMonth name="CIM"

CheckInDay name="CID"

CheckInYear name="CIY"

//and//

CheckOutMonth name="COM"

CheckOutDay name="COD"

CheckOutYear name="COY"

... I don't know how to do this. Can someone help?

I currently have this code returning the start and end date but don't have any code for getting and returning the month, day and year ...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var nights = parseInt($('#numOfNights').val());
    var depart = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', dateStr);
    depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + nights);
    $('#departureDate').val(depart);
    }
    });

    $('#numOfNights').change(function() {
    var nights = parseInt($('#numOfNights').val());
    var depart = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $('#arrivalDate').val());
    depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + nights);
    $('#departureDate').val(depart);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For number of days, you could just use a normal input. You could then listen for when the value changes, and then you could do the math to add the entered amount of days to the selected start date to get your Check Out date

Comment: I edited my question do be more specific. I am not a Javascripter, I just copied the code from his forum.